# "Waves is not defined" error while including material design bootstrap with webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design, webpack-2

I am using webpack to include [mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/)

This is how I am including it in my Project:

```
require('mdbootstrap/css/mdb.min.css');
require('mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js');
```

I tried `require('mdbootstrap')` also, but in both the cases I am getting the following error:

```
vendor.js:71728 Uncaught ReferenceError: Waves is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:71728)
at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:71729)
at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:20)
at Object._require.modules (vendor.js:68202)
at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (vendor.js:68186)
at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (vendor.js:63)
at vendor.js:66
```

Using `require('mdbootstrap/css/mdb.min.css');` alone works, but I need a js file too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i worked with:

cmd: `npm install node-waves`

main.js File

```
var waves = required('node-waves')
window.Waves = waves
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using **Vue**, this is the solution that worked for me:

**Install node-waves**:

```
npm install node-waves --save
```

**Declare it in webpack** (in both webpack.dev.conf.js and webpack.prod.conf.js):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'Waves': 'node-waves'
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I also come across this problem, and I find code of Waves.js in mdb.js file, so you don't need install node-waves.
The solution I google is comment those code in mdb.js

```js
Waves.attach(‘.btn, .btn-floating’, [‘waves-light’]);
Waves.attach(‘.waves-light’, [‘waves-light’]);
Waves.attach(‘.navbar-nav a:not(.navbar-brand), .nav-icons li a, .navbar form, .nav-tabs .nav-item’, [‘waves-light’]);
Waves.attach(‘.pager li a’, [‘waves-light’]);
Waves.attach(‘.pagination .page-item .page-link’, [‘waves-effect’]);
Waves.init();/* FORMS */
```

This is work for me. My mdb version is 4.3.2.